# My Xamarin.Forms app for Android no longer needs STORAGE permission, but it continues to show in settings App Manager

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, itext, sqlite-net

I am only creating an ANDROID app, but using .FORMS.

I have scrubbed the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE & WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions from every place that I can find in VS2017, including the Android Manifest (checkboxes, and checked the .xml file), and AssemblyInfo.cs & MainActivity.cs.

I've done a clean, and deleted the bin & obj directories.

I've also done a deploy only, and found these permissions already in place.

Lastly, I've found that it is only READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE that is showing up.

What did I miss?  Could this be a NuGet package, like  Xam.iTextSharpLGPL, or sqlite-net-pcl?  How could I find out?

Comment: Why did you need to remove this permission from your project?

Comment: I guess that's a reasonable question -- best answer I have is that I don't want to ask more permissions than I need to.  Does that make sense?